# log(A/B) = log(A)-log(B), where A and B have units

Tags: logarithms, unit-of-measure

We all know that

$$\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right) = \log(A)-\log(B)$$

However, in the case where $A$ and $B$ have (identical) units, such as kilograms, the right-hand side cannot be performed because the arguments are not dimensionless. How can one rationalize this observation without making the circular argument to convert the right-hand side back to the left-hand side when you have units?

Comment: $\log(A/{\rm unit})-\log(B/{\rm unit})$.

Comment: To be clear, I am aware that this is obviously how you'd evaluate such an expression, but strictly speaking, you have introduce the "divide by unit" to get the quantity to be dimensionless. That is rather unsatisfying.

Answer (score 2):

In the physical sciences we often come across quantities (like potentials, phases, and levels) such that only *differences* (or quotients) of quantities are directly observable, but we still want a workable calculus of such quantities without having to choose a reference value. This idea is made rigorous by the notion of [torsor](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html)—a group that has "forgotten" its identity.

In your case

- the domain of $\log$ is the "multiplicative" torsor of values that a positive quantity can take (where we have forgotten what units the quantity is given in)
- the range is the "additive" torsor of [levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_(logarithmic_quantity)) for that quantity (where we have forgotten the reference level), and
- the equality given is the statement that $\log$ is a homomorphism between these two torsors. If you had a definition of $\log$ that didn't depend on the $\log$ between the underlying groups, you could potentially prove that this is a homomorphism directly.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the unit like a variable:

$$\log\left(\dfrac{A \cdot kg}{B \cdot kg}\right) = \log(A) + \log(kg) - \log(B) - \log(kg) = \log(A) - \log(B)$$

After all, that's what you're doing when you say the units cancel.

Comment: No, this makes no sense. The expression $\log(kg)$ is meaningless.

Comment: If $\log(kg)$ is meaningless, then so is any operation on a unit, including division.  Therefore you can't say $\dfrac{kg}{kg} =1$.  So which is it, can units be operated on or not?

Comment: $A/{\rm unit}$ is really poor notation for "the numerical value of $A$", meaning, if $A=r\, {\rm units}$, the number $r$.

Comment: You can think of A kg as $A\cdot1kg$. Put ones in front of the kgs and proceed as shown in the answer.

Comment: @Daniel No, $\log(1kg)$ is still meaningless.

Comment: @AndyWalls I agree with the above comment. This explanation is still unsatisfactory because it simply restates the problem statement. You still have the issue that $\log(1\cdot\text{kg})$ or $\log(\text{kg})$, regardless of how you write that, is the logarithm of a quantity with dimensions. You have just changed $A$ and $B$ to be a numerical value instead of a value with units. Just because there is a $\log(\text{kg})$ terms that subtract out doesn't make the explanation any clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I have to side with Daniel Gendin here; this is the approach that the BIPM’s SI handbook outlines: $\rm kg$ is a specified amount of mass, and measurements in kilograms are really just a scalar multiplication of $\rm kg$ like how one might scale another mathematical quantity, like a vector. This leads to advantageous notation, like units canceling and a nice way to label axes or table columns, like $m/{\rm kg}$ as the header of a column of mass measurements in kilograms, where $\rm kg$ does not have to be repeated over and over. This is all specified as part of the SI.

Comment: That the handbook does it that way, or is established convention, does not make it meaningful, this is really not an issue of taking sides. If the point of the question was whether there is a standard, fine (even if out of scope for this site). But that didn't seem to be the question.

Comment: I'm in total agreement with @AndrésE.Caicedo. Take an expression like $\sin(kg)$ and Taylor expand it: $\sin(kg)= (kg) - (kg)^{3}/3! + (kg)^{5}/5! +\ldots$ Even if you ignore the fact that cubing a kilogram doesn't make sense, you're adding terms of different dimensions together. The same is true if you try to take the logarithm of a kilogram.